# Object with the same keys as another object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a method `produce` with the following signature:

```
interface ProduceConditions {
    [key: string]: Function|Promise<any>;
}

produce(conditions: ProduceConditions, input: any): Promise<object>|object;
```

The thing is that the returned (resolved) object has the same keys as the `conditions` object.

Comment: Please google for `keyof`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, your input `conditions` will be an implementation of `ProduceConditions` with some set of keys, and the return value (whether or not wrapped in a promise) will have the same keys but with the values all resolved.

In which case, the signature you're looking for would be something like:

```
produce<T extends ProduceConditions, U extends { [key in keyof T]: any }>(conditions: T, input: any): Promise<U> | U
```

Here I've used two generic types to represent the input and the output, with the requirement that the input type `T` meets the definition of `ProduceConditions` and the output type `U` has the same keys as `T`.

Comment: I can't imagine you want the return value to be generic, given that signature.  The caller chooses (or TypeScript infers at the call site) the types of `T` and `U`.  How could the implementation guarantee that it will return a `U`?  For example: `produce<{ dog: () => string }, { cat: number, dog: boolean }>(...)`?

Comment: @jcalz I assumed they have specific input and output types, but you may be right; in that case, you’d just replace the Us in the output with the T-based definition.

Answer (score 14):

If the input is supposed to be an object whose values are functions or promises and the output is an object with those functions called or promises resolved, then you can use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) to specify that constraint:

```
type ProduceConditionsMapper<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: ((input: T[K]) => void) | Promise<T[K]>;
}

declare function produce<T>(conditions: ProduceConditionsMapper<T>, input: any): T;
```

In action:

```
declare const func: (x: number) => void;    
declare const prom: Promise<string>;
const produceConditions = {
  cat: func,
  dog: prom
}

const ret = produce(produceConditions, 'hmm');
// inferred as {cat: number; dog: string;}
```

I'm not sure what the relationship between `input` and the other types are, but it's likely you could give it a more specific type than `any` for even better results.  Anyway, hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you @jcalz for the suggestion. It will take me some time to fully understand your example, as in Typescript context I am a 'noob'. As for the `input` type - `input` is any as I have no knowledge about its possible type.