# Is it possible (yet) to return an input object with its types mapped per property?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In short, I want a function which takes an non-predefined type like this:

```
{
  name: string,
  list: Array,
  metadata: Object,
}
```

and returns this

```
{
  name: MyStringProxy,
  list: MyArrayProxy,
  metadata: MyObjectProxy,
}
```

---

I know how to get an object returned where every property has the same type ([Object with the same keys as another object in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46511552/object-with-the-same-keys-as-another-object-in-typescript))...

```
abstract function allPropsAre42<TYPE_IN>(obj: TYPE_IN): { [key in keyof TYPE_IN]: 42 };
```

...which is a good starting point, but it only maps everything to one type.  I want to map each type to another.

---

I'm pretty sure it isn't possible, but here's some made up pseudo-code which would be like what I'm looking for:

```
interface IPropMap {
  string: MyStringProxy,
  Array: MyListProxy,
  Object: MyObjectProxy,
}
// not real code
abstract function mapAllProps<TYPE_IN>(obj: TYPE_IN): { 
 [key in keyof TYPE_IN]: IPropMap[TYPE_IN[key]]
};
```

**Is it possible to do such a thing in typescript?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types

Figured it out.  Using conditional type mapping, this can be done:

```
type TypeName<T> =
    T extends string ? MyStringProxy :
    T extends Array ? MyArrayProxy :
    T extends object ? MyObjectProxy :
    undefined;


abstract function mapAllProps<TYPE_IN>(obj: TYPE_IN): { 
 [key in keyof TYPE_IN]: TypeName[TYPE_IN[key]]
};
```

My guess wasn't too far off.

Comment: Note that the code here and the code in the question will not compile without errors.  Presumably `MyXXXProxy` are your own types, but `Array` requires a generic type parameter like `Array<any>`.  Also, `T extends object ? MyObjectProxy: T extends Array<any> ? MyArrayProxy : undefined` will never produce `MyArrayProxy`, since `Array<any>` itself extends `object`.  If you care about this, you should reverse the order of the check.  It's always helpful for code to constitute a [mcve] so others can reproduce both the issue in the question and the suggestions in the answers.